# SQL: Joining two tables and selecting top N in group from one table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using MsAccess and will upsize to sql soon.

I have this scenario:

Table 1 : `UserID` `Name`

Table 2 : `GradeID` `Date Grade` `UserID`

What I want to do is join both tables in a query or report to list all users alphabetically and their latest 2 grades. I looked up 'top n in group' solutions but can't figure them out or many didn't work. Currently I use Inner Join but that list all grades

Solution should look like:

```
User1 John Grade30 date grade
user1 John Grade29 date grade
user2 bob  Grade41 date grade
user2 bob  Grade13 date grade
```

thank you!

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. But first of all read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky in MS Access.  One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*, t2.grade, t2.date
from table1 as t1 inner join
     table2 as t2
     on t1.userId = t2.userId
where t2.date in (select top (2) tt2.date
                  from table2 as tt2
                  where tt2.userId = t2.userId
                  order by tt2.date
                 );
```